# VideoPlayer Shows Error (1, -1)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-video-player

I am working on playing a video in my application, and I am observing some strange results in doing so. Videos that I am trying to play are on server and I have to get them to run android's native videoplayer. 
I have tested the results on several devices and it is found that video runs on devices having OS version greater than equal ton 2.3.3 but does not run on others, showing error (1, -1). Now my question is that either the later OS versions have some extra Video codecs and format support and that is because the video gets played on them or it's something else? Why so is this error on few devices not on all?

**Devices on which Video Works fine in native videopalyer:**

Samsung Google Nexus with OS 4.0.1

Samsung Galaxy S with OS 2.3.3

**Devices on which does not get played:**

HTC-Desire with OS 2.2

Samsung Galaxy S with OS 2.2

Any help about the issue is always appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution??? This happens to me too...

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur due to many reasons. Issue might lie videoplayer, as well source from where you are reading the video, Is video coming from HTTp server or RSTP server...any of these can be the reason. You'll have to check accordingly. In our case, we solved it by using Video View and also made changes to URL to get it played.